# Group join in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am trying to group join in EF core 3.1 the problem it returns

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core

my code is like this

```
 var employees = await (from enrollment in RepositoryContext.Enrollments
                join allowance in RepositoryContext.Allowances.Include(y=>y.AllowanceType) on enrollment.EmployeeId equals allowance.EmployeeId
                    into allowances

                select new
                {
                    enrollment,
                    allowances

                }
            ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

the **allowances** is list of items ,
is there any workaround to run the query like this cause i need it for better berformance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here [Query with GroupBy or GroupJoin throws exception](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068) is the now closed GitHub issue/discussion where I was trying to convince EF Core team to add `GroupJoin` translation. They refused to do that and opened the useless [Query: Support GroupJoin when it is final query operator #19930](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930) where I continue the fight for such translation. So please go there and comment/vote up for the full translation request.

You will also find there the workaround - instead of unsupported `GroupJoin` use the equivalent supported correlated subquery approach, e.g. replace

```
join allowance in RepositoryContext.Allowances.Include(y => y.AllowanceType)
    on enrollment.EmployeeId equals allowance.EmployeeId
into allowances
```

with

```
let allowances = RepositoryContext.Allowances.Include(y => y.AllowanceType)
    .Where(allowance => enrollment.EmployeeId == allowance.EmployeeId)
```

Comment: Thanks i will upvote and comment, using let will increase the requests on database am i right?

Comment: @MustafaMohamed More votes on GitHub feature request increase the chance the feature to be considered/implemented.